# What is the logic behind Madara's plan A for his revival?

Tags: naruto

Uchiha Madara's plan A for his revival was to make Uzumaki Nagato use Rinnegan's revival jutsu (Gedo Rinnei Tensei no Jutsu). However, when Nagato used this jutsu to revive everyone in Konoha, he mentioned that he cannot revive everyone. He can only revive those that only recently killed as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Another version of the translation is more clear in that there is a time limit to how long someone can die before he is brought back to life using this jutsu.

[image]

Which means that if one died long time ago, it would be impossible to brought back using this jutsu. This also fits the fact that he didn't use the jutsu to revive Yahiko. Because he can't.

After he used it, everyone was revived to the state right before they died.

[image]

Madara died of old age. If Nagato revived him using that jutsu, wouldn't Madara be revived as the old Madara that's about to die? Is this a miss on Madara's part? What is the logic behind Madara's revival plan? Why do Madara think that his plan A is a perfect plan (or the better plan), as shown when he complained to Obito about being brought back to life using Edo Tensei?

Comment: A word of advice:  stick to the official translations.

Answer (score 3):

The complete limits of the Rinnegan have never been shown. Nagato did not actually say he could only revive the recently dead, just that he was not too late to revive Konoha. The best guess is that it takes more chakra to revive someone who has been dead a long time, and Nagato was very low on chakra after his fight with the village and Naruto. He consumed all of his remaining chakra when he used Rinne Rebirth and died because of lack of chakra. The full limits of rebirth were never actually given and the jutsu was only used twice in very different circumstances. When the King of Hell was used to revive the Asura Path (mechanical) when it was in pieces, it was put back together.

Edit: Also note, Obito used the jutsu and had all 9 Tailed Beasts extracted from him in less than an hour, but still survived and was able to fight not long after that.

Also, I do not know how to link images, but if I did, I would post one that should be on the same chapter as the first ones you linked, a few pages earlier, which has Konan specifically talking to Nagato, saying something about using the Rinne Rebirth jutsu at his current chakra levels. The specific words are based on the translation, but they all heavily imply that he did not have enough chakra to both use Rinne Rebirth and live. We know chakra exhaustion will kill a Shinobi directly from Kakashi, who used Kamui and exhausted his charka. He still lived after that for at least a few panels to accept his coming death before he actually died. Nagato had just fought an entire village almost alone, then blew it up, and then fought the Nine Tails and barely lost. He for certain had used up a massive amount of chakra, and reviving tens of thousands of people probably costs a ton of chakra as well. He was still alive after the jutsu was done for a little bit before his death, same as Kakashi.

Comment: See my update on the question. Nagato clearly said that there is still time to save those killed when he came to Konoha, which implies that there is no time to save those killed before.

Comment: I did address that already. Nagato NEVER said WHY he could not save them if he waited a while, BUT he also NEVER said that he could not save them after that time. Basic logic means that there are limits, but he does not actually say what they are. He only says that time is a factor, but nothing about how it actually affects the jutsu. As i said it could just be the amount of chakra required to revive someone is greater as time goes on, and Nagato has used up almost all of his chakra by the time he casts his jutsu.

Answer (score -1):

On the [wiki page](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Outer_Path_%E2%80%94_Samsara_of_Heavenly_Life_Technique) they say

> The deceased individuals' souls may be recalled from even the crossroad between life and the afterlife, returning to their **rejuvenated** bodies.

So Madara could have been revived with his young body

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if a context is provided or with a bit more detailed explanation. Right now, its just a copy paste of some claim in the Wikia.